# Grep data and output to file

Tags: sed, cygwin, grep

I'm attempting to extract data from log files and organise it systematically. I have about 9 log files which are ~100mb each in size.

What I'm trying to do is: Extract multiple *chunks* from each log file, and for each chunk extracted, I would like to create a new file and save this extracted data to it. Each chunk has a clear start and end point.

Basically, I have made some progress and am able to extract the data I need, however, I've hit a wall in trying to figure out how to create a new file for each matched chunk.

I'm unable to use a programming language like Python or Perl, due to the constraints of my environment. So please excuse the messy command.

My command thus far:

```
find Logs\ 13Sept/Log_00000000*.log -type f -exec \
sed -n '/LRE Starting chunk/,/LRE Ending chunk/p' {} \; | \
grep -v -A1 -B1 "Starting chunk" > Logs\ 13Sept/Chunks/test.txt
```

The `LRE Starting chunk` and `LRE Ending chunk` are my boundaries. Right now my command works, but it saves *all* matched chunks to one file (whose size is becoming exessive).

How do I go about creating a *new* file for each match and add the matched content to it? keeping in mind that each file could hold multiple chunks and is not limited to one chunk per file.

Comment: Is there one chunk in each matched file, or several? It doesn't really matter except for how to generate a file name for each extracted chunk. Also do I interpret the intention of the final grep correctly, you want to remove the starting chunk separator? If so, what's with the -B1 -- that will include the separator after all?

Comment: @triplee: That grep command may be a bit messy, but my intention was to add +1 line at the start and +1 line at the end of each match.

Comment: So you want the last line from the preceding chunk, and the first line of this chunk, and nothing else? You should still clarify the expected output and the structure of the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
find Logs\ 13Sept/Log_00000000*.log -type f -print | while read file; do \
sed -n '/LRE Starting chunk/,/LRE Ending chunk/p' "$file" | \
grep -v -A1 -B1 "Starting chunk" > "Logs 13Sept/Chunks/$file.chunk.txt";
done
```

This loops over the find results and executes for each file and then create one $file.chunk.txt for each of the files.

Answer (score 2):

Probably need something more programmable than sed: I'm assuming awk is available.

```
awk '
    /LRE Ending chunk/ {printing = 0}
    printing {print > "chunk" n ".txt"}
    /LRE Starting chunk/ {printing = 1; n++}
' *.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
find Logs\ 13Sept/Log_00000000*.log -type f -exec \
sed -n '/LRE Starting chunk/,/LRE Ending chunk/{;/LRE .*ing chunk/d;w\
'"{}.chunk"';}' {} \;
```

This uses sed's `w` command to write to a file named (inputfile).chunk. If that is not acceptable, perhaps you can use sh -c '...' to pass in a small shell script to wrap the sed command with. (Or is a shell script also prohibited for some reason?)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use `csplit` to do the splitting, then truncate the output files at the chunk end.